# Using TreeSets for ArrayAdapters Equivalent instead of ArrayLists

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, treeset

Because ArrayLists are not particularly efficient, I would like to use a TreeSet in my Android App that will add items, and display them in alphanumeric order. Is there anything similar to an ArrayAdapter that I could use in order to more efficiently display the items within the TreeSet to the user?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `are not particularly` - ?

Comment: *efficient* for insertion/deletion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use whichever data structure you'd like by extending [BaseAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html). By extending BaseAdapter you can override the [getView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29) method and pass the correctly formatted view using your TreeSet as the data structure. This [post](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/13/custom-baseadapters/) shows a nice example of a BaseAdapter implementation, now they are using a List still but you can easily see how to implement the same thing using a TreeSet.

Comment: Thank you for showing me with this. However for the getItem should I just return the entire TreeSet? I am not entirely sure what to do re this